# requests.get to localhost is timing out

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, wsgi, falconframework

I'm trying to do http request from one handler to another but it is timing out. Why? Using request library works but not with 127.0.0.1

```
# sample.py
import falcon
import json
import requests

class TS:
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        output = {
            'output': 'DataService.',
            'author': 'Python3'
        }
        resp2 = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/a')
        resp.body = json.dumps(output)
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200

class SE:
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        output = {
            'output': 'Service.',
            'author': 'Python3'
        }

        resp.body = json.dumps(output)

api = falcon.API()
api.add_route('/a', SE())
api.add_route('/t', TS())
```

I get this error log

`[2017-02-02 20:41:05 +0100] [27515] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:27544)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running this using `gunicorn` from the command line as shown in the tutorial:

```
$ gunicorn sample:api
```

That means that gunicorn is started with the default of [one worker process](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-processes) which is a [sync worker](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-class) with [one thread](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#threads).

This setup can only handle one request at a time, any further request will block until the previous has completed. So if you try to make a request from within your application to the same server you'll have a deadlock.

For this to work you can increase the number of worker processes and threads, e.g:

```
$ gunicorn --workers 2 --threads 4 sample:api
```